# Use actionbutton to display box() and table initially hidden, but then use it only for the subseting of the table

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I want to create a shinydashboard in which I have in the sidebar a `selectinput()` with all the column names of `iris` dataset, in the main body inside a `box()` we have a datatable of `iris` which is subseted by the `selectInput()`, and an `actiobutton()` below it out of the box.

When the app starts neither the box not the table are displayed. when I click on the `actionbutton()` the box with the subseted table are displayed. Then if I change the `selectInput()` choices nothing happens, but then if I click on the `actionbutton()` the subset takes place. The box remains there for the whole period now and never hidden again.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

# Define UI
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Subset Iris Dataset"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    selectInput("columns_selected", "Select Columns", choices = colnames(iris), multiple = TRUE)
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    
        fluidRow(
          box(
            title = "Subsetted Iris Data",
            width = 12,
            DTOutput("subset_table"),
          ),
          actionButton("subset_button", "Subset Data")
        )
  )
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  # Load the iris dataset
  data <- iris
  
  observeEvent(input$subset_button, {
    columns_selected <- input$columns_selected
    if (!is.null(columns_selected)) {
      data_subset <- data[, columns_selected, drop = FALSE]
      output$subset_table <- renderDT({
        datatable(data_subset)
      })
      show("subset_table")
    }
  })
  
  observe({
    hide("subset_table")
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: So, it is not clear what is supposed to happen when you change `selectInput()` selections.

Comment: It looks like your missing the dependency `library(shinyjs)`. With that added, it seems to work as intended

Comment: nothing, but when I press ACTIONBUTTON it triggers, but the box stays there

Comment: no its not working as intended @Marcus. initially there should be nothing displayed in the main body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the table to be hidden when changing the selections, you can hide it in an observer.  Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
library(shinyjs)

# Define UI
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Subset Iris Dataset"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    selectInput("columns_selected", "Select Columns", choices = colnames(iris), multiple = TRUE)
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    fluidRow(
      box(
        title = "Subsetted Iris Data",
        width = 12,
        DTOutput("subset_table"),
      ),
      actionButton("subset_button", "Subset Data")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  # Load the iris dataset
  data <- iris
  
  data_subset <- eventReactive(input$subset_button, { 
    columns_selected <- input$columns_selected
    if (is.null(columns_selected)) { df <- NULL
    }else {
      df <- data[, columns_selected, drop = FALSE]
    }
    df
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$subset_button, {
    if (!is.null(input$columns_selected)) {
      show("subset_table")
    }
  })
  
  output$subset_table <- renderDT({
    datatable(data_subset())
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$columns_selected, {
    shinyjs::hide("subset_table")
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```